# What does "$x->Put" do in Perl?

Tags: perl, put

I am looking at this piece of code:

```
$diag_cmd = pack("CCSV", DIAG_SUBSYS_CMD_F, DIAG_SUBSYS_PWRDB, PWRDB_DIAG_PKT_SCRIPT | $processor_select, length($s_part)) . $s_part;

     $diag_request_var = Variant(VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1, length $diag_cmd);
  $diag_request_var->Put($diag_cmd);
```

where Variant is defined below:

```
sub Variant {
    return Win32::OLE::Variant->new(@_);
}
```

I am not sure what does it do and what does PUT actually do in Perl.

Any ideas?

Comment: it depends on what `$diag_request_var` is.

Comment: $diag_request_var is a variant

Comment: `variant` is not a perl term, so doesn't really tell us anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Put` is not a standard function that comes with Perl.

In this case, you have an object named `$diag_request_var` which is of class [`Win32::OLE::Variant`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE::Variant). [`Put`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE::Variant#Put-DIM-VALUE) is a method of this object.

To know the standard functions that come with Perl, please see: [`perldoc perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html)

### Reference

[`Put(DIM, VALUE)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE::Variant#Put-DIM-VALUE)

Comment: `$diag_request_var` *could* be a class, not an object (though the name makes this unlikely)

Comment: $diag_request_var is a variant

Comment: @Californicated - it's not a "variant". It's a variable of class "Win32::OLE::Variant". It helps to be technically precise